# Trimming strings (date, time) in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am kind of new to python and pandas.

I have a rather large dataset (~500.000 rows). The first column contains the date and time in the form of

```
                      created_at
0 Sun Jul 26 04:06:58 +0000 2020
1 Sun Jul 26 04:08:22 +0000 2020
2 Sun Jul 26 04:24:10 +0000 2020
3 Sun Jul 26 04:27:10 +0000 2020
```

As a first step I would like to trim that to only the month and day to get a result like this:

```
created_at
0 Jul 26
1 Jul 26
2 Jul 26
3 Jul 26
```

Ideally I would like to have it like this in the end:

```
created_at
0 07_26
1 07_26
2 07_26
3 07_26
```

Can anyone help me with some efficient methods to do that?
I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Have a look into the `.dt.strftime` function.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `parse_dates` with column name in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and then for custom format is used [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('file', parse_dates=['created_at'])

#for first
df['created_at'] = df['created_at'].dt.strftime("%b %d")
#for second
df['created_at'] = df['created_at'].dt.strftime('%m_%d')
print (df)
  created_at
0      07_26
1      07_26
2      07_26
3      07_26
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [28]: df = pd.read_csv('a.csv')

In [29]: df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])

In [30]: df
Out[30]:
                 created_at
0 2020-07-26 04:06:58+00:00
1 2020-07-26 04:08:22+00:00
2 2020-07-26 04:24:10+00:00
3 2020-07-26 04:27:10+00:00

In [31]: df.dtypes
Out[31]:
created_at    datetime64[ns, UTC]
dtype: object

In [32]: df.created_at.dt.strftime("%b %d")
Out[32]:
0    Jul 26
1    Jul 26
2    Jul 26
3    Jul 26
Name: created_at, dtype: object

In [33]: df.created_at.dt.strftime("%m_%d")
Out[33]:
0    07_26
1    07_26
2    07_26
3    07_26
Name: created_at, dtype: object
```

OR

You can use the parameter `parse_dates` during loading the csv file itself

```
df = pd.read_csv('a.csv', parse_dates=['created_at'])
```